# How To Enable Autoplay in Nivo Slider HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#nivoslider-style-1').nivoSlider({
  effect: 'random',
  slices: 15,
  boxCols: 8,
  boxRows: 4,
  animSpeed: 500,
  pauseTime: 5000,
  startSlide: 0,
  directionNav: false,
  controlNavThumbs: false,
  pauseOnHover: false,
  manualAdvance: true
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>My guess would be to change startSlide: 0 to startSlide: 1</strike>

Scratch that. You have manualAdvance: true and it should be false. Be sure to change startSlide back to 0.

Comment: Thanx Buddy It's Working

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark question as solved. Thanks!