# How do I make nivo slider autoplay?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
$.fn.nivoSlider.defaults = {
    effect: 'random',
    slices: 15,
    boxCols: 8,
    boxRows: 4,
    animSpeed: 500,
    pauseTime: 3000,
    startSlide: 0,
    directionNav: true,
    controlNav: true,
    controlNavThumbs: false,
    pauseOnHover: true,
    manualAdvance: false,
    prevText: 'Prev',
    nextText: 'Next',
    randomStart: false,
    beforeChange: function(){},
    afterChange: function(){},
    slideshowEnd: function(){},
    lastSlide: function(){},
    afterLoad: function(){}
};
```

Comment: Add more details ...what you have tried. explain the actual problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43361393/how-to-enable-autoplay-in-nivo-slider-html